# How can I label an equation as (*)

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

Here is the code which has an equation in the form of `\[... \]`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Proof-} Every element of $\Delta(G)\Delta(G,N)\subset N'$ can be written as \((x-1)y(n-1)\) where \(x,y\in G\) and \(n\in N\). Now, because we can write \((x-1)y=xy-y=(xy-1)-(y-1)\) we also can write every $(g-1)$ in the form : \[g-1=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}(x_i-1)(n_j-1), \hspace{2pt}\ a_{ij}\in \mathbb{Z}, x_i\in G, n_j\in N \]
\end{document}
```

My question is how to label the last formula as `(*)`? All the answers I can find has aligned equations, but in this case I only have one `\[...\]` equation which I want to label. One way is to use `\hspace` and then put label,  but is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Use the `\tag{<your label>}` command to insert a custom label as you wish like this `\tag{*}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Proof-} Every element of $\Delta(G)\Delta(G,N)\subset N'$ can be written as \((x-1)y(n-1)\) where \(x,y\in G\) and \(n\in N\). Now, because we can write \((x-1)y=xy-y=(xy-1)-(y-1)\) we also can write every $(g-1)$ in the form : \[g-1=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}(x_i-1)(n_j-1), \hspace{2pt}\ a_{ij}\in \mathbb{Z}, x_i\in G, n_j\in N \tag{*}\]
\end{document}
```