# How to tag an equation?

Tags: math-mode, labels

I am typing in texmaker but using `\tag{}` is not giving me the desired result. It shows an error. Here is sample

```
\textbf{Proof-} It is clear that $Inn(G)\subseteq Aut_U(G)$. 
So we let  $\varphi \in Aut_U(G)$ i.e. $\varphi(g)=u^{-1}gu$ for some
$u\in U(\mathbb{Z}G)$\\
$\therefore$ $u=g^{-1}u\varphi(g) \tag{*}$.
```

Error says -

```
! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.
See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.... 
$\therefore$ $u=g^{-1}u\varphi(g)\tag
```

I am using `amsmath` package

Comment: Tag belongs on display math and cannot be used like you do here. Btw: please don't make proofs like this, use an environment to make the proof and add the proof headline. For example by using amsthm

Comment: @daleif Do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: Also, you have asked a rather similar question before: [How can I label an equation as (*)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256587/30280)

Answer (score 2):

Tags belongs on display math and cannot be used like you do here (on inline math).

Btw: please don't make proofs like this, use an environment to make the proof and add the proof headline. For example by using amsthm